# Swift 4: Passing a string in UICollectionViewCell to UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to pass this string from one UICollectionViewCell to UICollectionViewController. I would like the "Let's Get Started!" to go on my navigation title... Below is my code and I can't figure out why the string isn't getting passed.

```
// UICOLLECTIONVIEWCELL --> This is the first UICollectionViewCell
    @objc func getStartedAction() {
        let confirmingTapActionButton1 = "Let's Get Started!"
        let signUpFlowController1 = SignUpFlowController()
        signUpFlowController1.welcomeCellPassedStringForAction1 = confirmingTapActionButton1
    }


// UICollectionViewController --> This is the second UICollectionViewController
    class SignUpFlowController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

        var welcomeCellPassedStringForAction1: String? = nil

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white

            // NAV BAR STUFF BELOW
            self.title = welcomeCellPassedStringForAction1

        }
```

Comment: How is this new controller linked to the presented UI?

Comment: Is the `UICollectionViewCell` inside the collection view of the `UICollectionViewController`?

Comment: No they're seperate

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a protocol

Make a protocol:

```
protocol NavTitleProtocol{
func setNavTitle(title: String)
}
```

Conform your CollectionViewController to the protocol and override the setNavTitle method:

```
extension YourCollectionViewController: NavTitleProtocol{
func setNavTitle(title: String) {
    self.title = title
}
}
```

In your cell, have a delegate property of type NavTitleProtocol:

```
class YourCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell{
var delegate: NavTitleProtocol?

@objc func getStartedAction() {
    let confirmingTapActionButton1 = "Let's Get Started!"
//   let signUpFlowController1 = SignUpFlowController()
//        signUpFlowController1.welcomeCellPassedStringForAction1 = confirmingTapActionButton1
    delegate?.setNavTitle(title: confirmingTapActionButton1)
}
}
```

Assign your collectionViewController as the delegate when you create the collectionView cell:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "YourIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! YourCollectionViewCell
    cell.delegate = self
}
```

When you perform the selector in your cell, the delegate property will be accessed and the method that you have overriden in your CollectionViewController will be called.

Comment: Thanks, I think what the issue is I need to reload the data on my UICollectioViewController to be able to see the title text appear. Let me see if thats the issue and get back to you!

Comment: Aren't you trying to update the NavigationBar title?

Answer (score 1):

First this line

```
let signUpFlowController1 = SignUpFlowController()
```

creates a new instance other than the shown one , so you have to use the delegate to catch the presented instance

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    cell.myInstance = self
}

class customCell:UICollectionViewCell {
    var myInstance:SignUpFlowController!

    @objc func getStartedAction() {
        let confirmingTapActionButton1 = "Let's Get Started!"
        myInstance.welcomeCellPassedStringForAction1 = confirmingTapActionButton1
    }
}
```

Comment: see edit ......... whether they are separate or not send the current presented instance to the class that will call it later to be sure it's the same object

Comment: Thanks, I think what the issue is I need to reload the data on my UICollectioViewController to be able to see the title text appear. Let me see if thats the issue and get back to you!